# Search button or textbox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, binary-search-tree

I have a problem! I want to do search button in DataGridView. I take out data via a button with code:

```
FileStream f1 = new FileStream("zapis.dat", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(f1);
int а = 0;
while (f1.Position < f1.Length)
{
    string data = br.ReadString();
    string sing = br.ReadString();
    string avtor = br.ReadString();
    string zagl = br.ReadString();
    string janr = br.ReadString();
    string ezik = br.ReadString();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(++а, ezik, zagl, avtor, janr, sing, data);
}
f1.Close();
```

My question is; what code I can write on another button or TextBox to search from this data. Can someone help me, because I trying with many code from internet but I can't understand it.

Comment: You can filter `DataGridView`s

Comment: If you can't understand the examples you have found then chances are you won't understand our answers either because they will be similar to all the examples that can be found online. I suggest you post the code for your best effort and describe what it is doing and what you want it to do. Then at least we have something we might be able to talk about specifically.

Comment: The binary reader ReadString() method does following : Reads a string from the current stream. The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.  Does the datafile conform to these requirements?

Comment: please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018663/search-buton-in-datagridview-with-textboxchanged

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a TextBox and add a `TextChanged`event handler for it. Inside of it you can use something around these lines:

```
var dataTable = dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable;
if(dataTable != null)
    dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: When I put your code it shows me that the dataGridView Fields does not exist. Maybe I can add someone system or? How i can fix it?

Comment: in your case you have to replace "dataGridViewFields" with "dataGridView1"